# Holding, Delaying, or Readying an Action? - Rules As Written

Tags: dnd-5e, actions, readied-action

Please point or link me to any official rules (rules as written) on when a character can delay, hold or ready an action for later in a round, instead of going on their initiative.

What does a character have to do to delay or hold an action during a round?

What actions are characters allowed to take when they delay?

Comment: I've marked your question as a dupe because I think it is trying to ask the same as that other question. This isn't a bad thing as this question might help others find that one. If that question doesn't answer it for you, please clarify for us how and why, and we'll see what needs to be done to help you.

Comment: thank you, I tried to search for a similar question and could not find one.